# .htaccess not working with .cfm pages on Railo

Tags: .htaccess, tomcat, railo

I want to do some very basic .htaccess stuff like block a directory by IP address. I know why this problem is happening, I just don't know how to fix it. I've read every post I can and there doesn't seem to be a consensus on how to fix it. Railo/Tomcat is grabbing control of the page before .htaccess rules are applied.

I am running Centos with Railo / Tomcat / Apache. I believe I am using mod_cfml, at least that's what's under the connector folder.

I have tried putting my .htaccess files in httpd.conf without any luck. I'm not sure I was doing that correctly, but I dropped the code into the virtual domain section of the site I'm working on.

Has anyone got this to work properly?

Answer (score 0):

On iis you can change the order modules run which would  solve that issue Asbyou would tell the htaccess module to run before mod_cfml
Can you do that on Apache?

Comment: I'm not sure, I think I read about the order of modules loading in httpd.conf, specifically the mod_cfml. I'll try to find out more about that.